# Load a queue from one thread and run it from another

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I have a thread that takes a long time to run.  It produces data that other threads use, but I don't want them to return any of that data to the UI until it is valid.

I want to create a queue filled with those functions that should not run until the long thread is done, then the long thread should start that queue when it is done.

The long thread is an asynchronous cloud service that pulls data from a remote device.

The other threads are UI buttons that update the display.  I want those to put the update functions in the queue to run when it is ready so that I don't block the UI thread.

Comment: Put a mutex on the data, allow multiple simultaneous read access (the "other threads") but exclusive write access (the "long thread")?